# Can I correct string outliers with a table lookup?

Tags: excel

I have a [image: table]. Column B is a code has varying trailing numbers based on it's assigned category in column A. You can see that rows two and three are an A1 group, but the trailing number after the last `.` is 03 for row 2 and 05 for row 3.

I have a table in cells E2:F7 showing what that trailing number after each code string should be based on what's in column A.

Column C shows a consistent classification for that trailing two digit number based on it's category in column A.

Is there a formula I can input to reference what the trailing 2 digits on each code should be based on column A and the reference table in columns E:F?

Comment: Sure, do a REPLACE of the RIGHT two characters based on a VLOOKUP. Or some similar variation.

Comment: @BigBen Like, `=replace(b2,17,2,vlookup(a2,E:F,2,false))`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B2,RIGHT(B2,2),VLOOKUP($A2,$E$2:$F$3,2,FALSE))
```

[image]